# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ results: string; }'.ts(2345)

Tags: typescript, react-native

When I'm trying to pass the result.nativeEvent.message to other function im getting the Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ results: string; } on `onUnityMessageController(result.nativeEvent.message)`.

I don't understand why the 'string' can't be assigned to paramater of 'string'.

**Unity.tsx**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import UnityView from '@azesmway/react-native-unity';
import { View, Button, NativeSyntheticEvent } from 'react-native';
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

interface IMessage {
  gameObject: string;
  methodName: string;
  message: string;
}

const Unity = ({ navigation, route }: { navigation: undefined, route: any }) => {
  const unityRef = useRef<UnityView>(null);

  const shape = route.params.shape;
  const color = route.params.color;

  const parsedMess = JSON.stringify(route.params);
  console.log(parsedMess);

  const closeUnity = () => {
    unityRef.current?.unloadUnity();
    navigation.goBack();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (unityRef?.current) {
      const message: IMessage = {
        gameObject: 'gameObject',
        methodName: 'methodName',
        message: 'message',
      };
      unityRef.current.postMessage(message.gameObject, message.methodName, message.message);
      if (shape != null && color != null) unityRef.current.postMessage("SceneManager", "startUnity", shape + ";" + color);
    }
  }, [shape, color]);



  const onUnityMessageController = ({ results }: { results: string }) => {
    console.log('onUnityMessage', results);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <UnityView
        ref={unityRef}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onUnityMessage={(result) => { onUnityMessageController(result.nativeEvent.message), console.log(result.nativeEvent.message) }} />
      <Button title="Close Unity Screen" onPress={() => closeUnity()} />
    </View >
  );
};

export default Unity;
```

result.nativeEvent.message comes from:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NativeSyntheticEvent, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
interface UnityMessage {
    message: string;
}
declare type ReactNativeUnityViewProps = {
    androidKeepPlayerMounted?: boolean;
    fullScreen?: boolean;
    onUnityMessage?: (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<UnityMessage>) => void;
    onPlayerUnload?: (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<void>) => void;
    onPlayerQuit?: (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<void>) => void;
    style?: ViewStyle;
};
export default class UnityView extends React.Component<ReactNativeUnityViewProps> {
    static defaultProps: {};
    constructor(props: ReactNativeUnityViewProps);
    postMessage(gameObject: string, methodName: string, message: string): void;
    unloadUnity(): void;
    pauseUnity(pause: boolean): void;
    resumeUnity(): void;
    private getCommand;
    private getProps;
    componentWillUnmount(): void;
    render(): JSX.Element;
}
export { };
```

Comment: It's not clear which line the error is pointing to. Please give the full error message in the question body, not in the question title. At some point you need to give an object instead of the string similiar to `onUnityMessageController({results: result.nativeEvent.message})` or change the function signature to accept a string instead of an object.

Comment: `({ results }: { results: string })` means your function wants an object of type `{ results: string }` and would afterwards destructure it via `{ results }` into a string variable that also happens to be called `results`. You still have to pass an object while the function itself works on the string inside.

Comment: and it gets even less obvious if you use explicit destructuring `({ b: second, a: first }: { a: string; b: string })`, that would give you the value of `b` inside `second` and the value of `a` inside `first` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing simple String as an argument to the function `onUnityMessageController` but your type check is expecting object.
So simply change your function likewise :

```
  const onUnityMessageController = (results : string) => {
    console.log('onUnityMessage', results);
  }
```

Comment: I agree, this line looks wrong `({ results }: { results: string })`